# Validation with Struts 2 Convention plugin on method level, not class level

Tags: validation, struts2

I have the a class, CouponAction, with two methods, initCoupon and addCoupon. I only want validation on the addCoupon method, not on class level where it tries to validate all methods.

this class with methods looks something like this

```
@Scope("prototype") @Controller

@Namespace("/coupon")

public class CouponAction extends BaseAjaxAction<Coupon> {

............

@Action(value = "initPaymentCoupons", results = {

@Result(location = "/jsp/order/coupon/paymentCoupon.jsp", name = "success")

    })

public String initCoupons(){

........

}


@Validations(requiredFields = {

@RequiredFieldValidator(fieldName = "couponCode", type = ValidatorType.FIELD, message = "Enter a coupon code")
 })

@Action(value = "/addCoupon", interceptorRefs=@InterceptorRef("jsonValidationWorkflowStack"),
            results = {

@Result(location = "/jsp/order/coupon/paymentCoupon.jsp", name = "success")

})

public String addCoupon() {

.......

}
```

Then I get:

```
2011-11-10 00:44:13,567 ERROR org.apache.struts2.components.ActionComponent.error:38 - Could not execute action: /coupon/initCoupons
No result defined for action vervik.actions.order.CouponAction and result input
```

All examples Iv seen uses the validation annotation on class level.
When I used xml I had a file:
CouponAction-addCoupon-validation.xml 
which only validation the addCoupon method.

How can I make it work with validation annotation?

Sources:

http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-InterceptorRefannotation

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/annotations.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i am aware is that When multiple methods are used to map different actions on the same class, and one of them is annotated with `@Validations`, those validators will be triggered for all the actions.

Solution seems to use annotated with `@SkipValidation` or `validateAnnotatedMethodOnly` is set to true in the "validation" interceptor.

```
<interceptor-ref name="validation">
    <param name="validateAnnotatedMethodOnly">true</param>
    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
</interceptor-ref>
```

refer the following link

[Struts2 Validation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation-annotation.html)

though even i have not worked with such case using annotation so hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@SkipValidation` annotation at the method level to bypass the initCoupons() method.